# Possessives ( 's )

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, attributive-nouns

I need to know which of these sentences is right ?

> My room light doesn't work.

or

> My room's light doesn't work.

Comment: The first one sounds more natural but you could argue that room-light should be hyphenated when written. The second is grammatically correct.

Comment: related: [Is it correct to say “I write children books” (not possessive case)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case)

Comment: related: [Confusion with possessives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123316/confusion-with-possessives)

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is definitely correct.

The first sentence is also correct. In that sentence, *room* is a [*noun modifier*](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/noun-modifiers) applied to *light*:

> We often use two nouns together to show that one thing is a part of something else:
>
> the village church; the car door; the kitchen window; the chair leg;
> my coat pocket;

Much like *the kitchen window* means *the window that is part of the kitchen*, the phrase *my room light* can mean *my light that is part of my room*.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, except that in the first case you need a hyphen. But I would probably say 'The light in my room's not working'. It is just a case of local usages, personal preferences etc.

Comment: +1 That or the second option; "room light", while technically correct, sounds stilted to me.